# Bootstrap button switch - Add another active class

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

If someone visit first time, I need to show red color active button. Then he switch between yes and no, I need to show another active color. Please look at the screen shots.

**First time**

[image]

**Switching between yes and no**

[image]

I tried with this code. It's only switching active class.

```js
$('.btn-switch').click(function() {
  var $group = $(this).closest('.form-group');
  $('.btn-switch', $group).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.btn-switch.active {
  background: #e46a5d!important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.btn {
  padding: 6px 51px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-switch-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch active">
          <span class="goods">Yes</span>
         </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch">
          <span class="services">No</span>
         </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to add another active class or any other method for doing this?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/41814/)

Comment: Opps. My mistake. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch the classes based on the condition.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */

$('.btn-switch').click(function() {
  $('.btn-switch').removeClass("active red blue");
  if ($(this).find('span').text() == "Yes")
    $(this).addClass('active red');
  else
    $(this).addClass('active blue');
});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.btn-switch.active {
  background: #e46a5d!important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.btn-switch.active.red {
  background: #e46a5d!important;
}

.btn-switch.active.blue {
  background: blue !important;
}

.btn {
  padding: 6px 51px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-switch-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch active">
        <span class="goods">Yes</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch">
        <span class="services">No</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CssSY When you click on the `NO` button the `No` button color will be blue. Is this hapening?

Comment: Yes. But when I click yes again I need to change that also. Anyway thanks. I got answer!

Comment: @CssSY but what if I click `YES` at first time without clicking on `NO`...Is this also be blue?

Comment: No. It's red. I changed my mind. I think I need your solution.

Comment: Nop. I'll figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want:

```js
$('.btn-switch').click(function () {
  var $group = $(this).closest('.form-group');
  $('.btn-switch', $group).removeClass("active").addClass("switching");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.btn-switch.active{
  background: #e46a5d !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.switching.active{
  background: #adf !important;
}


.btn{
  padding: 6px 51px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-switch-justified">
 <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch active">
  <span class="goods">Yes</span>
 </button>
</div>
 <div class="btn-group">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch">
  <span class="services">No</span>
 </button>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are life savior! Thank you!

Comment: If any method for changing border color once for both yes and no fields?